# Поиск различных чётных натуральных делителей чисел в определённом промежутке

Tags: python

Нужно написать программу, которая ищет среди целых чисел, принадлежащих числовому отрезку [125 256; 125 330], числа, имеющие ровно шесть различных чётных натуральных делителей. Для каждого найденного числа записать эти шесть делителей в шесть соседних столбцов на экране с новой строки. Делители в строке должны следовать в порядке возрастания.

Например, в диапазоне [2; 48] ровно шесть чётных различных натуральных делителей имеют числа 24, 36 и 40, поэтому для этого диапазона вывод на экране должен содержать следующие значения:

2 4 6 8 12 24

2 4 6 12 18 36

2 4 8 10 20 40

То, как я попытался решить эту задачу:

```python
a = 125256
b = 125330
for n in range(a, b+1):
    ds = []
    for d in range(2, n//2+1): #честно говоря, не до конца понимаю, какую функцию выполняет здесь n//2+1
        if n%d == 0:
            ds.append(d)
            if len(ds) > 6:
                break
    if len(ds) == 6:
        print(ds[0], ds[1], ds[2], ds[3], ds[4], ds[5])
#по-моему, 7-я строка должна выглядеть так: if n%d == 0 and d%2 == 0:
#но тогда на экран вообще ничего не выводится
```

Хотелось бы услышать от людей, которые в пайтоне разбираются, что я делаю не так.

Comment: не понял - `[2 4 6 12 18 36] [2 4 8 10 20 40]` - это называется различные делители или имеется в виду, что само число должно иметь ровно 6 делителей?

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Код не работает совсем, или работает не так, что-то еще?

Comment: @Эникейщик код работает не так, как нужно, не совпадает с ответом. Выводит все натуральные делители (чётные и нечётные), а должен только чётные

Comment: значит нужно а) проверять на четность (этого можно избежать, если в d будут только четные числа), б) посмотреть внимательно на примеры из задачи. Там в выводе есть само число, а в вашем выводе его никогда не будет, что уже само по себе не даст правильного результата.

Comment: @Zhihar на примере показывается, что число должно иметь 6 различных натуральных делителя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот такой вариант правильно проходит ваш тестовый пример:

```
a = 2 # 125256
b = 48 #125330
k = 0
for n in range(a, b+1, 2):
    ds = []
    for d in range(2, n//2 + 1, 2):
        if n%d == 0:
            ds.append(d)
            if len(ds) > 6:
                break
    ds.append(n)
    if len(ds) == 6:
        print(n, '-', ds[0], ds[1], ds[2], ds[3], ds[4], ds[5])
```

Вывод:

```
24 - 2 4 6 8 12 24
36 - 2 4 6 12 18 36
40 - 2 4 8 10 20 40
```

Пояснения:

- Перебирать имеет смысл только чётные числа, у нечётных чисел не будет чётных делителей, поэтому шаг `2` в цикле по `n` (сокращаем перебор в 2 раза)
- Делители тоже имеет смысл перебирать только чётные - ведь таково условие, поэтому в цикле по `d` я тоже поставил шаг `2` (сокращаем перебор в 2 раза)
- Само число тоже считается своим делителем, судя по приведённому примеру, поэтому я его добавил в список вручную после окончания цикла. Можно это делать и до начала цикла, но тогда в списке числа получаются не по порядку, поэтому добавляю в конце, просто для красоты.
- Перебор сделан до `n//2 + 1` потому, что если число чётное, значит оно делится на `2`, делителей меньше чем `2` быть не может, значит перебор имеет смысл вести только до `n//2` (а само `n` я добавляю потом отдельно), `+1` же тут из-за особенностей работы `range` - конечное значение не включается в перебор, поэтому надо добавить `1` (итого - опять же сокращаем перебор ещё в 2 раза).

Результат для чисел из самого задания:

```
125262 - 2 6 18 13918 41754 125262
125288 - 2 4 8 31322 62644 125288
125298 - 2 6 18 13922 41766 125298
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for d in range(2, n//2+1): #честно говоря, не до конца понимаю, какую функцию выполняет здесь n//2+1
```

т.е. вы написали код и не понимаете что вы написали? или вы его списали?

ну сначала надо разобраться как вообще должен выглядеть алгоритм

если считать, что 1 не является делителем, то тогда вам надо

1. для каждого числа `n` пройтись от числам `i` от 2 до  `n` включительно и попытаться разделить число `n` на `i`
2. если деление происходит без остатка (модуль равен 0) и делитель - четный, то +1 к кол-ву найденных делителей

   ```
    for n in range(a, b + 1):
        count = 0
        for j in range(2, n + 1):
            if n % j == 0 and j % 2 == 0:
                count += 1

        if count == 6:
            print("нашли")
   ```

очевидно, что `n` для самого себя является делителем, а ближайший более маленький делитель - это `n / 2`, просто потому что `0 < n / (n / 2 + j) < 1`

поэтому счетчик делителей можно начинать с 1 и перебирать числа только до `n / 2`:

единственное что вначале надо проверить а является ли `n` - четным

```
count = int(n % 2 == 0)
```

чтобы не делать много `if else` просто перевел булево значение в целочисленное

```
for n in range(a, b + 1):
    count = int(n % 2 == 0)
    for j in range(2, n // 2 + 1):
        if n % j == 0 and j % 2 == 0:
            count += 1

    if count == 6:
        print("нашли")
```

в данном случае

```
n // 2 + 1
```

чтобы гарантированно захватить половину числа `n` при переборе

Если надо вывести делители, то тогда всего лишь в код надо добавить их сбор (учесть, что 1 делитель мы знаем всегда - это `n`)

```
for n in range(a, b + 1):
    count = int(n % 2 == 0)
    dividers = [n] if n % 2 == 0 else []
    for j in range(2, n // 2 + 1):
        if n % j == 0 and j % 2 == 0:
            count += 1
            dividers.append(j)

    if count == 6:            
        print(*sorted(dividers))
```

Comment: PS. Нас интересуют только четные делители, а не вообще все ;)

Comment: `n//2+1` делать нельзя, так как число тоже является делителем самого себя, а оно может быть четным

Comment: @Zhihar Да, списал с одного сайта эту строчку, когда искал способ перебора натуральных делителей, а сам так и не понял, что это значит. Но вы всё доходчиво объяснили, спасибо!

Comment: @Gladius так перед выполнением цикла мы это проверяем же

Comment: @Zhihar а, понял))

Answer (score 0):

Если править ваш код, получится следующее:

```py
a = 125256
b = 125330
for n in range(a, b+1):
    ds = []
    for d in range(2, n+1): # т.к. a и b небольшие, можно рассмотреть все делители числа
        if n%d == 0:
            if d % 2 == 0: ds.append(d) # верно, на этом шаге проверяем, что делитель четный
        # if len(ds) > 6: избыточный код, незначительно ускоряет решение
        #     break
    if len(ds) == 6:
        print(ds[0], ds[1], ds[2], ds[3], ds[4], ds[5])
```

Оптимальное решение такое:

1. Перебираем все числа
2. Каждое число делим на все числа до корня включительно.
3. Каждый раз получаем два делителя (делитель и частное), если какой-то из них четный — сохраняем.

```py
for n in range(125256, 125330 +1):
    counter = set() # множество вместо списка, избегаем повторы
    for d in range(1, int(n ** 0.5) + 1): # перебор до корня включительно
        if n % d == d % 2 == 0: counter.add(d) # сохраняем делитель, если он четный
        if n % d == n // d % 2 == 0: counter.add(n // d) # сохраняем частное (на него число тоже делится), если оно четное
    if len(counter) == 6: # если делителей шесть
        print(*sorted(counter)) # выводим их в порядке возрастания
```